# UWP Using FolderPicker to add just defined file types

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I try to select from a folder only desired files as follows:

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker
        {
            ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop
        };
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
```

All other file types except files like `".mp3"`, `".mp4"`, `".jpeg"`, `".jpg"` and `".png"` should not be selected. But unfortunately the code also adds all other files that have not been added to FileTypeFilter.

What is missing in the code?

Comment: I don't think the `FolderPicker` filters away files. Maybe you want to use a `FileOpenPicker` instead?

Comment: @mm8 If `FolderPicker` offers the `FileTypeFilter()` method, then file filtering must be possible or not? I also want to select all the files in the folder, not just a single file.

Comment: There is a `PickMultipleFilesAsync()` method that lets you select multiple files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker. Apparently filtering a `FolderPicker` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below (Microsoft  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers)

```
 var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
 picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
 picker.SuggestedStartLocation = 
 Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
 picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
 picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
 picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

 Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```